# Intel 8080 Instruction at OP Code 0x20 and 0x30

Tags: assembly, intel-8080

According to Intel's 8080-8085 Assembly Language Programming guide, the OP Code `20` corresponds to the Read Interrupt Mask (RIM) instruction, and `30` corresponds to the Set Interrupt Mask (SIM) instruction.

[image: instructions]

However, only the 8085 has the RST5.5, RST6.5, and RST7.5 hardware interrupts.  Are the instructions at `0x20` and `0x30` just `NOP` on 8080 hardware?

Comment: I assume it still has the masking register, so you could read back what you have written. Try it? :)

Comment: According to this 0x20 and 0x30 on the 8080 are treated as NOPs : http://pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8085 has 2 instruction functions:

- To read and set the interrupt mask.
- To communicate via serial port interface.

On 8080, these opcodes are NOPs.